# Compiler Optimization In Visual Studio Code Go Debugging

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, compiler-optimization

When stepping through my code using VSCode debugging, I see it skip lines or jump around in such a way that suggests it is jumping through optimized code. For example, it will skip lines where I have breakpoints set, even though I expect the line to be executed. Is `go test` running with compiler optimizations enabled? If so, is there a way to disable those optimizations? Either in the the `go test` command line or with VSCode settings? I tried `-gcflags='-N -l'` in my launch.json for a test configuration but it is not recognized.

Comment: Is it possible it's jumping around because you have multiple goroutines running concurrently?

Comment: Good question. I should have noted that the code that I was stepping through doesn't invoke any goroutines.